# Loop the result and get scanInfo.level

Tags: android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver, wifimanager

I am trying to loop over the results of `wifiManager` scan of access points to return the RSSI strength (dbm). What I have so far:

```
public class MyWifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          boolean a= wifiManager.startScan();//request a scan for access points
          List<ScanResult> results= wifiManager.getScanResults();
      }
 }
```

Comment: and the question is? btw. you forgott a closing curving bracket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyWifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          final WifiManager lWifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          boolean a= lWifiManager.startScan();//request a scan for access points
          final List<ScanResult> lResults= lWifiManager.getScanResults();
          for(final ScanResult lScanResult : lResults){
            System.out.println("ScanResult level: "+lScanResult.level);
          }       
       }
}
```

should do what you need.
As far as I see `level` is a public class member of `ScanResult`.